# It is time that we have a Super Downvote!

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, super-downvotes

In keeping with [today's theme](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405582/it-is-time-we-abolish-downvoting) I'd like to revive [a very](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/should-we-have-a-small-number-of-supervotes-per-day) old [request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21279/can-we-have-a-kind-of-super-upvote-for-unexpectedly-awesome-answers): we should have a limited number of Super Downvotes to use each day as we see fit.

[image: Bugs Bunny with a nine-shooter, Yosemite Sam with a ten-shooter]

My reasoning is simple: folks enjoy downvoting, and In These Dark Times we need to maximize whatever enjoyment we can scrounge up!

For years, folks have treated *closing* as a super downvote, [but that's just wrong and you should be ashamed of yourself for thinking otherwise](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one). The two systems are orthogonal, and should be treated as such. But... It's so hard to do that, when racked by temptation.

So let us be led no longer into temptation, but give us our daily super downvote and allow us to be at peace!

### Mock-up

[image: a bigger downvote button below the normal downvote button]

Comment: I was about to suggest a super-upvote to compensate, but we have that already: bounties... It'd only be fair to add a super-dv!

Comment: the purge but for Stack Overflow

Comment: Do we get mod powers during the purge? Just ban everyone. We can't be "unwelcoming" if there's noone here.

Comment: Can you clarify if this "Super Downvote" is meant to be for users who like downvoting, or is it for users who use close-votes as super downvotes? Or is it both?

Comment: Both, @cigien. Why should we limit who can be a part of such joy?

Comment: Because for the second group, this proposal is next to useless. The users who close questions they don't like, want to *actually* close the question. Super downvotes are not going to give them that, and so they will continue closing questions they want to close.

Comment: I usually don't wish to close questions. And I cannot close answers. But often I wish to downvote them many times!

Comment: Will I be able to Super Downvote myself if I've been very bad?

Comment: I have no opinions on your kinks, @blastfurnace; you do you.

Comment: What makes you think that a super-downvote will prevent treating closing as an extra super downvote on top of the super-downvote? We already have downvote, close-vote and deleting-voting going on from the same users, no?

Comment: Um, I did sleep more than usual last night. Is it April 1st already?

Comment: Closing and deleting are about removing things from the site, @scratte. Downvotes are about Registering Disapproval.

Comment: @Shog9 So? Whatever means one can use to get those annoying "no-effort no-debug how-to" Questions out of the way. A super-downvote will just make it easier. I doubt they'll be used instead of close-voting. I'm almost certain they'll be used on top of it.

Comment: You're arguing vigilantism, @Scratte. I get it: Batman is cool. But we are a society of rules and order!

Comment: I'm not sure about that. You're relying on people keeping with the rules, while you at the same time acknowledge that they're using close votes as super-downvotes, hence: They're already breaking the rules. Possibly related: [Can we slow down on the deletes, people?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405585/can-we-slow-down-on-the-deletes-folks)

Comment: [Not sure if serious.](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ca/0e/f8/ca0ef80929bd8af86f6a9c61b521a387.png)

Comment: Not April, @41686d6564 - [Friday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfVsfOSbJY0)

Comment: What effect would it have on the post? Will it delete it? Will it hide it from everyone else? Will it prevent low-quality answers? The proposal needs some details.

Comment: YES, let's see just how crazy chit can get!

Comment: Will it do something therapeutic like play a bubble wrap popping sound on click?

Comment: [Friday? ... in Iceland!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21413/241919)

Comment: I remind everyone that we had a "thank you" feature: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction so it worth testing a "super downvote"

Comment: Is it similar to that nuke button mods have next to every users name?

Comment: Would a Super Downvote (on an answer) come with an accordingly Super Reputation Cost? (-5 points anyone?) And should Super Downvotes on questions still be free?

Comment: Could you clarify whether this proposal is for Super Downvotes on Meta, or on Main, or on both? At the moment there are answers that treat this proposal as if it's about enabling this feature on Meta, and other answers (mine included), that treat this proposal as enabling this feature primarily on Main. Your proposal doesn't make this clear.

Comment: Can I super-downvote this very question?

Comment: And here I thought this was an announcement about Shog10

Comment: Can this one go up to 11?

Comment: Are you intending that other users can see the super downvotes, or would a script be able to take care of it? Maybe with an explosion of the post after hitting the button 50 times?

Comment: Did I really get Rebecca'd by Shog9 now? I mean I was away a long time but that's harsh bro.

Comment: And... what does this *do*?

Comment: It is not so much that I need a superdownvote or a superupvote button, I need a feature so that I can hit a button extra hard. BAM! you know?

Comment: @Cerbrus Instead of super-downvote, missed the chance to call them "bounties and downties"

Answer (score 46):

I disagree with limiting it. We might have a better solution. The anti bounty! Spend reputation to cost reputation for a particularly bad post.

It will let high rep users finally put the fear of dog on the undeserving.

5k and up to get a user suspended. 100k for a 10 year suspension.

It can't fail

<sub>tongue firmly in cheek. May contain nuts</sub>

Comment: While you're claiming this answer is tongue in cheek, I suspect it might be taking this proposal exactly as seriously as it was meant to be taken. I'm refraining from upvoting this answer until the [fun] tag is added to the question though.

Comment: I also think *something* contains nuts, and I suspect the lack of fun tag is intentional. Explaining the joke or telling someone something is a joke isn't.... funny

Comment: Yeah, making a joke *obvious* isn't funny. On the other hand, if it's not clear enough that something is a joke, it runs the risk of wasting people's time because they take it seriously. If this "feature-request" *is* a joke, then it's disrespectful to the several users who've taken the time to give thought out responses. It's much better to have a joke fall flat than to waste people's time I feel.

Comment: I would definitely use this feature. I don't understand what you mean by tongue in cheek but I like this idea.

Comment: I love this feature. Please implement it, it's probably the best [tag:feature-request] I've seen in a while.

Comment: lol, imagine we spend reputation on a post so that upvoting it incurs a reputation penalty until our bounty runs course.

Comment: Hard disagree, unless negative reputation becomes a thing. Worst posts come from low-rep users, making this suggestion inefficient.

Comment: Most spam is made by 1 rep accounts, would you really spend reputation on a question that's going to get deleted by a user that's going to get deleted?

Answer (score 19):

[image]

---

For the record:

- I get the joke.  Close votes and deletion as super-downvotes has been a meme since time immemorial.
- I get the reference.  You were making light of a situation that happened/boiled over on Meta.  That's fine IMO.
- I get that there's a lot of people who are interested in having a heart-felt discussion over what a "super downvote" actually is.

...but honestly, this is the only face I can muster right now.  You baited some folks out with this one, but for those who think that a super downvote is exactly what we need...you get the look above.

Comment: Oh, so this feature request was not meant to be taken seriously at all?

Comment: @cigien I think you'll find (with a modicum of investigation) that the OP would have had ample time (and, certainly, the *means*) to implement this feature, in a past existence, had he really wanted to.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, I know they could have, but maybe they didn't want to, and now changed their mind, or they would have liked to, but it wasn't a priority? Anyway, I get the idea, this whole post is a joke. It's in poor taste IMO, given the strong feelings people have about the topic. Maybe it was clear enough that this post is a joke, and I simply missed it; I don't claim to have the best grasp of what counts as humor.

Comment: Bugs Bunny not sufficient clue? Poor taste - not sure; Meta is about *discussion*, and this post has certainly provoked *that*. And - just possibly - taken some of the 'heat' out of recent, related posts?

Comment: It's a response to the discussion.  I love Shog and know what he's doing here, but this honestly represents my raw, unfiltered emotions.

Comment: @AdrianMole Like I said, I don't claim to have a good grasp of what's funny or not. It's mildly annoying to me that I would need that in order to have a discussion on Meta. I suppose that's on me, and I guess I should just learn to recognize this form of humor better. Anyway, I'm deleting my answer since it was not written in the same spirit as the question itself. Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: @cigien Keep your Answer. Even if the Question is meant as a joke, the merits of it isn't. Some users want this.. (BTW: I didn't get the joke either at first.)

Comment: @Scratte No, I think how people use their votes is a valuable and important discussion to have, and I would rather do that in a Meta that's trying to address that seriously. Users are more than welcome to their jokes, of course, I'd just rather not make a serious argument when the premise is not serious. It's just a personal preference when it comes to means of discourse.

Comment: @cigien I understand, but look at the Answers. Some are very serious and I feel they are just as important as the joke ones. Also notice that the joke ones have a message just like the serious ones do. I liked your Answer and so did others, which is obvious since it had a score of 7. (The premise is serious enough, it's only the delivery that was joking around)

Comment: @Scratte Sure, I'm not saying that the question can't be answered, it's just that I didn't answer it when I understood what the question actually meant. Now that I know, I might give it some thought and write a better answer.

Comment: Wait, so you say people *did* think this is a serious feature request (unless this is meta irony)? :) I was really starting to worry if that is the case after the 3rd deadpan-serious answer.

Comment: awww Makoto pls let people enjoy things!

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier:  Have your fun; I'll just be shouting in my yard...

Comment: And yet, it has its own tag.  [Let's burnate it.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407528/8384089)

Answer (score 17):

Unfortunately without a clear suggestion in how this would improve the quality of posts on the site this proposal has no merit.

There are times I wish I could cast 10 or 100 downvotes on a single answer, but this is to counter whatever upvotes it might have or to show how terribly bad the solution proposed really is. I don't think this applies to questions. Questions are just vessels for answers. If a question is going to attract low-quality answers then it needs to be closed and deleted. Downvoting the question heavily won't do any good.

I actually believe that if we are to get super-downvote, then it should only apply to answers, same as the bounty does. Something like a negative bounty would make sense, but it doesn't really solve the problem of low-quality answers. The best option would be to remove them or hide them from plain sight.

**Allowing people to super-downvote questions would only make the current problem worse.** People often use questions to retaliate, letting them cast super-downvotes would allow them to have super-revenge.

If a question truly deserves super-downvotes then it probably also deserves to be closed and deleted. Why would we keep otherwise something that is so terrible? If the question has good answers, then it should be rewritten. Either way, we already have tools that act in place of super-downvotes. We can close and delete such questions, which is the ultimate goal of it. We want to prevent answers and hide them away.

**Downvotes are not a means to hurt the user who posted it. They are means to curate the content and let others know not to waste time reading the post.**

Answer (score 11):

While this idea may be a bit ridiculous... I would not mind having it on Meta...

On the other hand, the real problem here is that Meta requires a more expressive system for voting. I always feel bad that I have to downvote (regardless of the "no reputation penalty" for Meta) some post that is really written and presented well, just because I don't agree with the idea or the premise.

I think that some additional venue for expressing agreement or disagreement would be nice.
Something like thumbs up, thumbs down. Maybe even +100 or -100 for things you feel very strongly about. And some suggestions are just *meh*.

Answer (score 9):

This feature is underspecified, which by itself is a hint. And I think I know what you're hinting at.

This isn't the first time the term *super downvote* is mentioned. It has been a tongue-in-cheek name for any other action of moderation with the intent to intensify what should otherwise be just a downvote. Whether this super downvote takes the form of a close vote or a delete vote, is frowned upon. Close votes are not for questions with a clear goal and topicality, but zero research effort. And delete votes are not for heavily downvoted answers and questions on Meta. However, despite these votes only being possible by supposedly reputable members of the site, they have occurred at least sporadically. Even if in a small amount, they could eventually provide more fuel to the bad image people paint about Stack Overflow.

With that said, it is a bit absurd to imagine a "super downvote" button being enough to lure users away from misusing the other actions. Instead, I would definitely go for features which help in **educating** about moderation on the platform, and **communication** between users on the Meta sites. A few concrete but unpolished ideas come to mind:

- Provide more tools to communicate on Meta sites. It does get tiring to explain everyone who's new to Meta that voting here is different. If we show a different set of operations to score or assess a question, not only it will already be clear that voting is different, it will also make an opportunity to design clearer actions on a post. For example, the "thanks" feature was a pretty bad idea in general, but [it could work on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/398550).
- Improve our guidelines and criteria for distinguishing Meta discussions *worth keeping* from those that should be taken away. From yesterday's incident, it is clear that we don't quite have a consensus on this. Like some people say¹, one person's WTF is another person's FTW. On the other hand, even a thoughtful and concerning question can be the source of unnecessary drama and unwarranted soapboxes for ill-posed opinions.
- When pressing *Delete*, present users with more information about when to vote to delete, rather than the overly simple prompt that we currently have.

¹ Definitely not something I found this one time on Twitter and grew in me since then.

Comment: Does FTW mean "Free The Whales"?

Comment: @Scratte For the win, its an acronym of common confusion...

Answer (score 9):

Why stop at Super *Down* Votes? We could have Super *Close* Votes; or, rather, *layers* of closure.

So, if a question is potentially closable for multiple reasons, then it can be closed multiple times. For example: Once for lacking details or clarity, again for being opinion-based, and again for being a duplicate.

Such questions would then require the appropriate (multiple) number of Reopen Votes to get them back into active life.

Here's an illustration of a possible model ([relevant link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_Comedy_Illustrated_by_Botticelli)):

[image]

Comment: You missed the Super Delete Vote: First one is a Hard delete. Second: Nukes the user. Third: Nukes the user across the network.

Comment: @Scratte But I play *by the rules* - votes are about *content*, not about the user! ;-P

Comment: I see. Maybe we could change it to "Nuke the site"?

Comment: @Scratte That would, actually, make more sense (within the literal definition of site rules).

Comment: @Scratte "Nuke all employees and moderators accounts" is before "Nuke the site". What do you think?

Comment: Also, how can a question be lacking details _and_ a duplicate? If such a question exists, then it shouldn't be closed as a duplicate, or the original duplicate should be closed.

Comment: @10Rep The illustrated model may be equally suitable for relocation of staff and/or moderators. In fact, perhaps even more so. ‎ (Though I would have to exclude *erstwhile* staff members, obviously! )‎

Comment: "exclude erstwhile staff members". You're hoping your Answer gets accepted.. tsk tsk ;)

Comment: @Scratte Can you blame a guy for tryin'? I'm just amazed there isn't a single downvote (super or otherwise); I suppose that will change, though.

Comment: That's kind of the point though. What exactly would voting on this answer mean? I frankly have no idea; does it mean I think your proposal is bad/good? Does it mean I find your joke, or reference, amusing?

Comment: @cigien Several people have described Meta using phrases similar to, *'Tis a strange place*. Not *every* post need be 100% serious. This one, though (possibly) one of Shog's jokes, does actually bring out some potential issues.

Comment: Absolutely, there are some very important things being discussed here. However, it not being clear whether it is a joke or not, is an issue. For example, there are users who sincerely believe that downvotes (and other votes) are used by the SO "elite" because they actually get off on making new users suffer. What signal does this Q&A send to those new users I wonder?

Comment: @cigien Probably best to let Shog9 answer that point. Anything I would say now would only be speculation. Shog works in mysterious ways.

Comment: @Scratte Fourth SDV: nukes the planet user (site?) is on

Comment: ..."it's the only way to be sure"    <Ripley>

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no one is asking this (maybe it is something everyone knows and I am new so I don't).

What is the reputation gate for this power? 2k rep? 10k rep? I can't imagine letting users with the downvote privilege have this privilege. The resulting mess would be *chaos* to say the least.

---

Also, what's the guarantee there won't be at least one user who decides they can now downvote, close, and super downvote on questions? It's impossible to predict what some people will do.

All in all, I think this is an OK idea, but it needs some more rethinking and the feature itself would have to have some limits to be useful in the *least*.

Comment: I'll propose the use of a super-downvote should disable any other voting on the post. Except for maybe "follow" ;)

Comment: LOL my answer is just in the endless void :)

Answer (score -3):

Most down- and close votes could be avoided if your users would be in a better mood. A grumpy user is not motivated to put a lot of effort in helping OPs to improve their posts, a grumpy user will simply down- and/or close vote and move on. A happy user is much more lenient to help the OP improving their post.

How is this connected to the super downvote? Easy: If a user super-downvotes more than one post of the same user, add some functionality that in the future the user no longer sees any posts from this OP. The user will be much happier if they can use their time and effort constructively to improve stackoverflow.

Comment: What if that user makes a good post? This seems like a social media feature where one user can block the other and it gives the wrong message.

Comment: @10Rep The risk of missing a potentially good post is totally worth it if all other posts are perceived in a better mood

Comment: It would be interesting to know what percentage of down/closevotes are on posts from users a user has never interacted with before. I would not be surprised if it's quite high. In which case this suggestion is likely to have minimal impact.

Answer (score -6):

Since the request didn't mention what super downvote will actually do, here is my suggestion.

- First super downvote on a post will reduce 10 points from the post author.
- Second super downvote on a post will reduce 50 points from the post author.
- Third super downvote on a post will reduce 100 points from the post author.
- Fourth super downvote on a post will reduce 500 points from the post author.
- Fifth super downvote on a post will reduce 1000 points from the post author and post automatic tweet alerting all the followers of this post.
- Any further super downvote will reduce 1000 points more from the post author.

Comment: While I agree with the sentiment, this would give it too much potential for abuse.

Comment: I'm not agreeing with your forth one. I think that should just reduce by 500 reputation points. And bring negative reputation to Stack. Fifth goes to -1000. With enough people using the super downvote on a post.. we can get the fabulous -1m reputation points. "It's not all the stuff you did that matters, it's the worst stuff you did that sticks."

Comment: @Scratte fair point, on second thought I won't like to delete something that can attract so much attention. Edited. :P

Comment: So kind of super-bounty with an immediate winner!

Comment: Why should it reduce reputation at all?

Comment: @Dharman because upvote increase the reputation.

Comment: Not penalizing enough! :) As normal DV costs 2^1, let's make super DV cost 2^2 1st time, 2^4 2nd, 2^8 3rd, 2^16 4th, and every other just reducing the score to 1. [please don't consider that]

Comment: Does the word "serial super downvoting" strike any terror? I've had posts serially downvoted 5 times, so I would lose half of my reputation.

Comment: @10Rep fair game though. Let's give them bigger weapons! ;-)

Comment: @OlegValter Let's consider it, among with the suggestion to make rep go below 1.  The servers would be overloaded with disassociation and account deletion requests.