# Why was this question closed as "Needs details or clarity"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66870994/8967612) by a new user yesterday when it was first posted. Then, in less than 15 minutes, the question already received 5 downvotes and was closed as "Needs details or clarity".

Well, as I said in a comment there:

> I have no idea why this question was closed as 'Needs details or clarity". The question might not be well written but the problem is 100% clear.

Yes, the question might not be well-written. Clearly, English is not the OP's first language and they seemed to be struggling a little bit. Maybe it deserves a downvote or maybe someone could step in and edit the question but I just think some people are too quick to close questions from new users just because they "look bad" at a first look.

Don't get me wrong. I do VTC questions within seconds if the question deserves to be closed. However, in this case, the problem in the question (at least to me) was perfectly clear **even in Revision 1**. Okay, maybe there was one missing detail in the question, that is, the version of Windows (or photo viewer) being used. However, it's not that important if the problem occurs in both Windows 7 and Windows 10.

I personally tried to come up with a solution for the OP's problem but everything I tried didn't work. I looked around and found some potential duplicates but none of them had an accepted answer and all the proposed solutions (which most of them I had already tried) didn't work either. So, it *is* a good question.

I had also edited the question to make it more clear and voted to reopen. The OP has also provided more details and a screenshot since then and I just edited the question again to reword and format it better. The outcome is: the question got out of the reopen queue and is still closed.

So, to summarize: three users voted to close the question (although it was clear, IMO), and three different users voted "leave closed" in the reopen queue.

**Am I missing something here?**

**Update:**

As per [yivi's suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406362/why-was-this-question-closed-as-needs-details-or-clarity#comment834098_406362) and went and edited the question even further and provided more attempts to solve the problem. I still do believe that the question was already clear enough and that `Process.Start()` is a sufficient MCVE in this particular situation.

Comment: It's tagged with code c# and doesn't show a specific c# coding problem?!?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How is _"I use `Process.Start(pathImage);` and I expect it to do X but it does Y. What is the alternative?"_ not a specific C# coding problem?

Comment: Way to less contex for diagnosing (as you experienced yourself). Missing MCVE.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What? `Process.Start(pathImage);` _is_ a MCVE in this situation. Are you not able to reproduce the problem with just this line of code (and an image path, obviously)? _"as you experienced yourself"_ I did not. I managed to repro as easily as can be.

Comment: And the exact content of `pathImage` is at that point? What's the encoding? Did the OP tell you their debugging observations.

Comment: It may be clear, but it's not well-researched or generally useful, so the downvote tooltip seems to apply. As previously [discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405590/7296893), some people use close votes as super downvotes, which might be what happened here as well

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ _"encoding"_ I'm not sure how that's relevant. _"debugging observations"_ What more observations do you need other than "the photo viewer opens but without navigation buttons"?

Comment: @ErikA As mentioned in the question above, I don't disagree with downvotes. I do however disagree with closing the question as "unclear" when the truth is otherwise. _"not well-researched"_ I can't speak for the OP and I don't know how much research they did but as mentioned above, I did my own (quick) research in hopes of finding a dup but I didn't find a working solution in similar posts.

Comment: The fact that it was clear to you doesn't mean it's going to be equally clear to others. You voted to reopen because you think the question is fine, maybe you can help the OP with further edits to make the question even better.

Comment: @yivi That's exactly what I did, twice so far. Is the question (as it stands right now) not clear to you? I'm genuinely asking, btw, as I might be wrong and it might be indeed unclear to others.

Comment: "*Am I missing something here?*" OK, maybe I am. How do I recreate OP's problem? I see the single line of code they used but I don't know any context, or how the application is run. I *could* write my own code, drop that single line in, then make up some path but am I recreating the same scenario? I'm not that good with C#, I must admit, so maybe there are details that are evident to you that aren't to me for how exactly that situation comes about. But here is the thing - future visitors are probably not likely to be as much of experts, either.

Comment: @41686d6564 And I'm not agreeing with the close votes either, I'm just saying this question fits a common pattern of misusing close votes which has been known about and has been discussed for years. This happens. And as an author, you can avoid it by writing good questions that don't merit these "super-downvotes"

Comment: I know you edited the question, that's why I said "further edits". I am not a subject matter expert. Generally, a single statement without adequate context is wouldn't be considered enough in the tags I frequent. It might be enough here. The screenshot with the combined view of a file selector and a Windows Explorer "folder" is kinda confusing as well, although it can be understood, eventually.

Comment: I simply mean that "unclear" is ultimately a subjective statement. "I cant fully  understand the question as it's stated". Some other users found it "unclear", best course of action is to improve the question in some ways.

Comment: @VLAZ _"How do I recreate OP's problem?"_ Step 1) find a local folder with several images and copy one of the images' path. Step 2) Call the single line of code posted by the OP replacing `pathImage` with the path you just copied. That's it.

Comment: In the end, the only ones who can tell you **why** they voted as they did are the close voters. We can only try to guess according to what we see.

Comment: @ErikA Agreed. Another reason why I believe the question deserves to see the light of the day is that the solutions I tried include providing a working directory with the file name being the image path, `"explorer.exe"`, and  `"ms-photos://"`, and yet, none of that worked.

Comment: It seems you did some work researching and trying things. I think that's great. Why not edit the question with those findings? It doesn't matter you are not the OP, it's improving the question preserving the author original meaning.

Comment: The OP reposted the question in SO.ru, where they [got an answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1263884/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c). I have even less Russian experience than in Windows, though.

Comment: That russian answer is generic & doesn't actually answer their problem, just suggests a different approach (without any details). @yivi

Comment: This is just sad. They're well on their way to a Question ban on Stack Overflow. They posted it on the Russian site after it getting closed here, and it was much better received there.

Comment: @yivi That's a good suggestion. I just did that. I still believe that it's unfair for new users to have this experience though just because we think that their question "looks bad" or looks similar to questions with no MCVE. We already get many unwarranted complaints from new users who ask actual bad questions. Let's not push away users who do try. That's just my two cents and that's the whole point of this post. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66870994/1) didn’t have a single line of code showing the community what they tried.  So of course it was closed. It’s unfair to the community for questions like this to take the focus away from questions that do provide code examples.  It’s not even clear if the code examples that have been provided were actually tried by the author.  “ Process.Start(pathImage);” didn’t appear in the original revision and wasn’t even provided by the author.

Comment: @SecurityHound As I said over and over again, `Process.Start()` (which is included in your linked revision) is a sufficient MCVE in this particular case. Yes, it was not a complete line of code, per se, in the first revision but not all questions that don't include code are bad (though most of them are).

Comment: @4168d6564 - They didn’t indicate they were trying to start a UWP application, what they provided absolutely in that case, was not a MCVE for that task.  Don’t let my profile fool you, I know what a 
MCVE C# example for this problem is, I am very familiar with C#

Comment: @41686d6564 call it from where? PowerShell? Create a new solution? Anything special I need to do when executing? Because there are quite relevant. At least to me. Don't know if it matters for a C# application opening an image but shell scripts might behave oddly if ran in one directory and targetting a file in another, vs running them in the same directory where the file is. So, if I run my own C# application, am I doing the same as OP is? Perhaps more pertinently, *why* should I write the entire code and try to guess details about it instead of, you know, being provided in the question?

Comment: @VLAZ _"So, if I run my own C# application, am I doing the same as OP is?"_ Yes. _"why should I write the entire code and try to guess details about it"_ That is true for other questions. For this particular problem, there are no details needed and the problem is reproducible. You do not have to write anything other than `Process.Start(@"some\file\path");`.

Comment: You say that but the author was attempting to launch a UWP application so that won’t work, since the folder the executable exists in is protected, so their application won’t have the required permissions.  Had they not resubmitted the question I would have answered their question.

Comment: @SecurityHound Please read the question carefully (and if you want, run the code yourself). Calling `Process.Start(@"C:\Foo\Bar.jpg");` _**will**_ open the UWP Photos app just fine. The only problem the OP was having is that it opens in a different way compared to double-clicking the image file in Windows Explorer, that is, the navigation buttons aren't there. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: So that’s what the random red circles in their image mean, how was I supposed to know that?

Comment: @SecurityHound From the first revision: _"but in this case it is not possible to switch between all images in the data folder"_. Yes, it's not described perfectly but I understood it the first time I read it **and** edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: _Calling Process.Start(@"C:\Foo\Bar.jpg");_ *will* _open the UWP Photos app just fine_ Not on my machine since I have a different programm associated with `jpg`. This could also be so on OP's machine. They then would have to use a different argument for `Process.Start` which they didn't provide.

Comment: @BillTür The OP said "the standard Windows photo viewer" though.

Comment: @41686d6564 "*"So, if I run my own C# application, am I doing the same as OP is?" Yes*" in that case, you'd probably be surprised just *how many* questions I've seen that go "I used X and it doesn't work" where it turns out X is one of 10 other things that was in their actual code and the real issue comes from basically everything else. We do ask for a MCVE for debugging questions for a reason.

Comment: @VLAZ No, I wouldn't be surprised because I experience those situations first hand as well. Why does everyone seem to ignore the fact that the problem is reproducible using the line of code presented by the OP? I did say that I managed to repro within seconds, right? If I didn't, _then_ I would've asked the OP for more details.

Comment: @41686d6564 - **Well I didn’t understand it.** Which is probably the reason others thought the question was unclear and downvoted the question and voted to close.  As for reproducing the problem, the author ran into this problem, since that’s how the application is supposed to work.  You don’t get the “data folders” when you open a photo by double clicking it.

Comment: @41686d6564 I've also been able to reproduce problems easily. Only to turn out that OP is having a different issue in the code they haven't shared. Maybe it worked in this case. It happens. But in general I think it's dangerous to keep assumptions about code problem where the code is unknown. Hence why we need the details.

Comment: @SecurityHound Yeah, that's a fair point. I can't argue with that.

Comment: One thing I'll add to this:  It can't be answered, at least not sanely.  Windows uses an undocumented IPC mechanism to communicate the intent from Explorer to the Photo App.  There is no documented command line to produce the same behavior.  I waffled on answering this when it was open, but answers that boil down to "it can't be done" tend to make things worse.

Comment: @Anon Coward: Well, isn't that just a shame...

Comment: **ALWAYS edit the question** and **NEVER post a new one**.  If you post a new one you are vulnerable to downvotes for deleting a question and or for posting a duplicate question.  I tried posting a new one and ended up with 4 downvotes in the process.

Comment: I suspect the q-ban algorithm has a good memory because some of the downvoted questions (which were deleted) that likely contributied to my q-ban are from 9 years back.  Although to be fair I haven't added many questions since then.

Answer (score 14):

The original question, for quick reference:

> I need to open an image from the code using standard Windows tools, I tried to do this using Process.Start, but in this case it is not possible to switch between all images in the data folder. how can i solve this problem?

1. What are the "standard Windows tools" they refer to? Here's what I believe is an example where a language barrier makes a question really, really difficult to understand. Native speakers generally don't associate "tools" with just consumer-facing apps such as Photos. The screenshot alone, behind a hyperlink as it was first provided, clarified the question *massively*.
2. The rest of the question doesn't make any sense until it's understood that the asker was referring to the Photos app. What could "switch between all images in the data folder" possibly mean? It could mean any number of things, not all of them related to a consumer app, or even a UI for that matter.

I don't see any other closeable issues with the question, but I'd argue this was enough to close it. If you were able to understand right away that the asker was referring to the Photos app even before they provided a screenshot, it would've been best to explain this to the rest or even edit it into the question, but even then you can't be 100% sure, so it was important that they provided the screenshot on their own.

After the addition of the screenshot the question does become answerable. Did it deserve being reopened at that point? Not sure, but the room for improvement was definitely there. Naming the Photos app in text (both in prose and in the image's alt text that you added) helps immensely, for one. The title has been significantly improved as well. After that, any other improvements to the question start to enter diminishing returns; like you said, `Process.Start()` was enough of an MCVE, though providing a path does at least give the asker and readers a chance to verify that there wasn't a typo or something. While I'd love to just trust that the path being used is valid, it never hurts to make sure.

I'm not clear on where the other attempts came from as I don't see any comments alluding to them, but I'm gonna trust that you knew what you were doing when you added them. Thank you for the additions.

> It's tagged with code c# and doesn't show a specific c# coding problem?!? – πάντα ῥεῖ

Asker is coding in C#. So asker tags their question [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), hoping to receive answers in C# that match the question and they can use instead of F#, VB.NET, or God forbid pseudocode. This is normal everyday behavior, and depending on the question and language even ensures that code samples are highlighted more accurately (not that it would've applied to this question in its original form, but it does now). What's wrong with it? It only becomes a problem when they start adding tags for languages they aren't working with.

Comment: You bring some good points. I probably should've made a more substantial edit in the early revisions. I just didn't want to make too many assumptions. That being said, the fact that the question has received three more downvotes and not a single (additional) reopen vote indicates that people (for some reason) think that the question is _still_ not clear. At this point, I'm not sure what else could be done.

Comment: As to the other attempts, that was a suggestion in the comments above. I didn't think the question needed them but I added them because I believe that a lot of users receive questions with "no code attempts" poorly regardless of the context.

Comment: @41686d6564: Yeah, that's the way it is on the internet: the more votes have been cast, the exponentially less likely all or even most of them are going to be revised after changes have been made. Some are just going to stick, no matter what. That's why first impressions are so important and the barrier to entry is so, at times brutally, high.