# Announcing "The Key™" - copy paste like you've never done before

Tags: discussion, announcement, april-fools

As we said in [our blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/31/the-key-copy-paste),

> Today marks a new beginning for programmers around the world. Stack Overflow is proud to unveil our first venture into hardware, The Key™.

*We all copy and paste*, be it in comments, close reasons or code. Every day you copy, *then you paste*. It’s a fundamental human experience that hasn’t been innovated for decades. Not to fret, we’re here for you!

One might say The Key™ looks like just another 3-key macro keyboard. *One would be wrong*. Our product & development teams spent the best part of the last year working on this product, making it perfect for the Stack Overflow user base and we’re very proud of announcing it today without any prior testing, because we’re sure it is amazing!

The idea of a 3-key keyboard for Stack Overflow isn’t new and many have talked about one. But, there’s a lot of little things that are great about The Key™; its amazing sound and key design, its perfectly molded plastic that massages your fingers and not to mention the *industrial grade lasers* involved. All the neat features can be found in [our blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/31/the-key-copy-paste). Go read it!

This is a revolutionary technology, and we’re still in our very first version of the product! For those of you who decide to be early adopters (as everyone should), we really want your feedback! When you get your very own “The Key™” (pre-orders open), come back and share all your thoughts, suggestions and feedback with us. Don’t forget to spread the word on how amazing it is to use. And if you happen to think it’s not, well, you’re just wrong.

We’re looking forward to having you get your hands on The Key™, and as we ramp up production, please share below what are the best keycap designs you’d like to see us make! The highest voted ideas might even make it into the final product, because we <3 people who vote. Speaking of votes, what will your Stack Overflow key command do? Vote, comment, mark as duplicate? Let us know what possibilities The Key™ unlocks for you.

Comment: Took me a while to realize it is April 1st somewhere.  Before that I was completely confused

Comment: I thought this is Apple anniversary. Copy paste reinvented.

Comment: Ugh... Didn't even notice the pop-up, wondered why clicks didn't put the keyboard cursor back in the answer I was editing. *grumble grumble bah humbug*

Comment: I was so mad when i saw the 2 copy pastes little notification, then when I clicked "learn more" was so confused xD

Comment: It's showing up as "Announcing &quot;The Key™&quot; - copy paste like you&#39;ve never done before" on "Featured on Meta".

Comment: Should be fixed, @AndrewGrimm

Comment: @ShadowRanger This is a bug that I'm working on right now. We're just trying to enhance your copying experience, we're not intending to impact your text selections. Sorry for the frustration!

Comment: Here's [one newbie user confused by this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66897290/how-do-i-combine-multiple-text-filled-rows-into-one-in-python?noredirect=1#comment118252710_66897290). It's a shame that it is getting in the way of users.

Comment: Despite the date, my (literally) 200 macro keys already have some of that functionality... One of the more complicated ones extracts the URLs from a page of bookmarks to a text file and (most importantly) deletes those bookmarks (there are of course other ways of doing that).

Comment: @ShadowRanger The popup bug where it steals your clicks and text selection is now fixed. Thankfully, I was able to copy and paste a fix with some of my remaining budget

Comment: I panicked for a minute.

Comment: I knew something's off because of that silly looking pop-up. Reading the blog post made it a whole lot weirder and I was able to confirm it as a prank after I clicked pre-order.

Comment: @Kyle any way to "reset" the counter back to two, after two copies? :/

Comment: I hope it does not append `[duplicate]` to my text every time I use it.

Comment: I managed to hake it!! change copyBudget in LocalStorage to as much as you want!! :)

Comment: This is fabulous :)

Comment: SE should make this a real feature, no more worries about money, and we'll get rid of most of the stup ... eh ... short questions.

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard yes in is in localStorage under copyBudget change it in the devtools of your browser

Comment: I thought it was a prank until I saw this post

Comment: Genuinely fell for it.

Comment: could be a useful tool if it also generates close votes by pressing `C` and `V` together

Comment: You may think I'm joking but I'm not: on my 3.000$ macbook pro the CMD key is defected and I always struggle with copying and pasting!
Your new device could solve my problems for only 39.99$ and those of a lot of unlucky mac users, please make it real!

Comment: I wish keyboards came with COPY, CUT, and PASTE keys... that small savings would add up.

Comment: well I cant believe that I fell for that!

Comment: @bob Some do... you just need a keyboard with macro keys on the left, e.g. Corsair do some (I haven't tried them).

Comment: @Steve Some people just aren't the type for this sort of thing :)

Comment: The copy/paste counter at the bottom right just counts down to 0 and stops there. After that, you can still copy and paste. You got me there!

Comment: @user13267 It's not a prank.
@holydragon It doesn't append `[duplicate]`.

Comment: Wait... how do you activate the pop-up?  I've been copying and pasting but nothing's happened.

Comment: @BlueStaggo I know now after seeing this post

Comment: @Anonymous you must have finished yours up for the day

Comment: I fell so perfectly for this, saw the message, thought what, dismissed it immediately from attention (but not from the screen), had to do one more copy, and another one, thought what the heck, seriously, are they introducing a feature in a strange way or really trying to make money. There only one more copy to see if something actually happens.
That really made my day >.<

Comment: Why not an Alt-Tab to make switching windows easier? That still needs to be 2 keys, though. Throw in a Windows/Mac key and an Alt-F4 key and you can practically get rid of the mouse altogether. Lol.

Comment: Damn near quit SO after seeing that message before I realized the date. I though the was some piece of <expletive deleted>, poorly advised money making scheme by some complete <expletive deleted>-ups in marketing.

Comment: @user4581301 You would've quit SO because of this?  After 6 years and 28k rep?

Comment: @EfraimNewman Wow, that's a real security hole.  [I'm reporting it.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406465/8384089)

Comment: @AndrewMorton How does it differ from The Key™?  Does it have a cookie instead of the SO logo?

Comment: @Anonymous The way I read the pop up was "You can only cut and paste one more time!" I can't adequately answer questions if I can't cut and paste. Site instantly became useless to me.

Comment: @user4581301 Honestly though, how long could a feature like that have lasted?  A million users would freak out and they'd be forced to remove it.

Comment: @Anonymous yup, but anyone who'd do something that stupid... Even for a few minutes... Wow. Mind you I'm on a bit of a hair trigger right now. Not quite in a good headspace.

Comment: Funny enough I was copying some comments out of my own answer when this happened. "You're going to charge me for access to *my own content*? Wow.". The price is a bit *too* realistic, exactly what I'd expect some niche thing like that to cost.

Comment: @jrh Wait for your first DMCA takedown notice on your own content :(

Comment: Aaaand this is why I detest the internet on this day.

Comment: [I've made a chat room for The Key™.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230649/the-key)  I'm surprised nobody else did that before me.

Comment: Instead of ignoring copy-pastes when you run out, it should go negative.  That would be pretty funny and make users even _more_ confused.

Comment: Well played! This does put a smile on my face :)

Comment: Ok, now that we're past April 1st. Can I actually buy this thing?

Comment: [Cassidy Williams was "responsible"](https://buttondown.email/cassidoo/archive/to-understand-is-to-invent-jean-piaget/) for this: *"This past week was a busy one because of a very, well, silly reason: April Fools’ Day! I helped a bunch in putting together both Netlify’s prank as well as Stack Overflow’s!"*

Answer (score 111):

I know this is an April Fools prank, but I'd love to actually order a little programmable macro-pad like this (probably not at $40 if it can be avoided). I'd argue this would be fun little merch item to own rather than a T-shirt or sticker.

Comment: It's a shame the Stream Deck costs so much.

Comment: [suspiciously similar](https://www.ebay.com/itm/3-keys-Gaming-Keyboard-Programming-Macro-Keypad-Mechanical-Keyboard-Software-OSU-/383796320336)

Comment: @RocketNikita I'd like to think that SO would be smart enough to be using USB-C in 2021 tho. You'd be able to support phones that way too :D

Comment: $40 isnt too bad of a price for a custom keycap (SO) and a decent case.  I so want this.

Comment: I agree! It's a really nice looking product. Wouldn't be surprised if soon there will be a knockoff version to buy somewhere...

Comment: I think for commonly-used features the benefit may be worth it: I use text editing in a computer all the time so I got the 200$+ Razer Naga mouse which has up to 12 buttons on its side and a feature to alt-function them, effectively doubling the amount of programmable buttons. My button #1: Copy. Button #2: Paste!  And I got 40 some other/extra ones functions to use - combine that with their Macro own creator, some custom AutoHotKey scripts and Windows multiple desktops and I'm almost as productive on my Windows PC as I am on a Mac with Keyboard Maestro! Lol!

Comment: Not before they add t-shirts back to a shop somewhere

Comment: I found this because I was searching to see if anyone else would buy this, and yep :D I would 100% get this, even if it was non-functional, just to hang in my office. What can we do to make this the [Tauntaun Sleeping Bag](https://news.avclub.com/april-fools-joke-backfires-on-thinkgeek-1798216223) of 2021?

Comment: Make your own for $6... https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-qt-py/circuitpython-hid-keyboard-and-mouse

Answer (score 67):

I'm concerned that you may now be facing a lawsuit, since this seems to be a blatant copy/paste of an existing product!

[image]

Comment: This has neither the "C" or the "V" key on it. I see no similarity.

Comment: @Octal Yeah because surely I wasn't joking or anything. I'm dead serious in my fear that SO is now facing a Microsoft lawsuit for patent infringement of this existing Microsoft product. Which was designed as early as for Windows 4.1.

Comment: Geez, you can stop with the downvotes guys, I'm fairly certain this is a joke. Hence the very specific wording 'blatant **copy/paste** of an existing product'

Comment: @szmate1618 Wait, are you saying that people on the Internet are sometimes posting jokes and memes?

Comment: Maybe they used The Key™ to achieve this.

Comment: I don't understand the name of this product. Isn't that actually a Windows Me keyboard?

Comment: @dfeuer This Special Edition works for CE, Me and NT, and they didn't want to name it CEMeNT Keyboard.

Comment: @Ray Especially Me... but was it released when this picture was posted?

Answer (score 55):

For a few seconds I got a mini-heart attack that my browser was infected.

Thank you for this new service though! love it!

Comment: I'm now tempted to make a virus now that actually does that on every site but stopping at zero.  On an unrelated note, would you [click here](https://sketchywebsite.net)?

Comment: @Anonymous I had a mini heart attack from that link... not cool

Comment: @10Rep It's a joke that links to a joke website.  Nobody is obligated to click it.

Comment: @Anonymous at least include a warning next time..

Comment: @10Rep If there is a next time, I'll add a warning.  Just curious, what were you expecting it to be a link to?

Comment: @Anonymous I was expecting a link to something similar to The Key or something, but it would be a fishy site with weird css or something.

Comment: @Anonymous I expected it to be NGGYU

Comment: @Anonymous nice try I’m on a iPad.

Answer (score 40):

A bit "chicken" on this, IMO :) Clicking the "Pre-order" quickly displays "April Fools’! We’ll never restrict your...". Seriously who would click "Pre-order" (even at that cheap price :) without knowing it's an April fool... Would have been funnier going one step further, with a crazy "Pay" page :)

Comment: I clicked it because I know that it immediately won't but it will lead me to an amazon page or something

Comment: [Agadmator rickrolled some](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jx_jySDkN0&t=11m56s)

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks, that reminds me that I  really have to change my user name ;)

Comment: I want "The Key"! So I clicked it.. it's awesome. I'm disappointed that it's not actually for sale ;)

Comment: It would be even funnier if you actually get to pay and not receive anything

Comment: @user13267 It would also be funny when users sue Stack Overflow for stealing their money.

Answer (score 28):

> what will your Stack Overflow key command do?

A [Super-Downvote©](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405590/it-is-time-that-we-have-a-super-downvote) of course...

---

On a serious note, please consider adding an <kbd>X</kbd> key for future versions. I find it really cumbersome to press the <kbd>C</kbd> button, then go back to my regular keyboard and press <kbd>delete</kbd> whenever I want to cut something. Let's not discriminate *cut*-pasting!

Comment: Copy text, paste it, copy emptiness, paste emptiness.

Comment: @RocketNikita, Your methods are unorthodox but effective.

Comment: @Octal Keyboard with X and V is the most effective.

Comment: Feature creep !

Answer (score 21):

I was disappointed when I clicked purchase -- this would actually make a great trinket or conversation piece to have on my work desk, so I kind of wish they were actually produced.

I really enjoyed ThinkGeek's april fools jokes when they made them, as the most interesting ones were actually turned into real projects. Is there a chance you actually do a production run of these?

Answer (score 17):

Ok but **major** props to the concept designers! The fact that they put enough effort into this design to make it look *this* professional and realistic... all for a joke... increases my faith in Stack Overflow... and all of humanity really.

PS: And wow apparently the Stack Overflow key looks *amazing* on a keyboard. I would legit buy a keyboard with that logo on it.

[image]

Comment: Funny... *"The fact that they put enough effort into this mockup [...] increases my faith in Stack Overflow"*. One would argue that such efforts should go to other much needed stuff around here, but yeah - it's pretty cool :D

Comment: @Tomerikoo This is a fair point. :P

Comment: Mockup? It's an actual real thing that works. https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/1377615767731048452

Answer (score 14):

They look pretty nice and neat, I actually want one with that special Stack Overflow keycap (maybe not at $40). It would be interesting to install it to my keyboard and set the macro to open SO every time I press the key :).

Comment: The keycap is certainly gorgeous. I would get two to replace C and V on my keyboard.

Answer (score 14):

Needs Dark Mode version: black keys with white lettering.

Ninja version also...

Comment: Ninja version has black letters on black keys, and can only be used in the dark?

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica I think you could also use it in the light.

Comment: Only if you're wearing a black body-suit with a black full-face-covering balaclava, black gloves, black slippers, inside a house or other building, with all the curtains drawn, and the window shades down, and the lights out, under a black blanket.

Comment: You already have the ninja version. You just don't know it.

Answer (score 13):

Am I the only one who thought for a second that this was XSS? When I saw an unexpected, obnoxious banner asking me to pay money on the threat of losing a basic feature of my operating system, my mind immediately jumped to foul play.

It would only have been more convincing if you set the price in bitcoin.

Comment: Maybe that's why they didn't set the price in Bitcoin.

Answer (score 11):

### Wow, new product disruption!

Congratulations for The Key™! I am very excited to have this amazing product from the site that helps me over my years of professional careers. The product is very elegant, minimalistic, combined with the no-nonsense functionality for copy-pasting and community service through the Stack Overflow key. That being said, however:

### Complaints/feedback regarding The Key™

Consider this, for reference (taken from the blog page):

[image: the key]

#### 1. THE KEYBOARD DIMENSION

I agree that the dimension of the keyboard (keypad?) should be small. After all, it has only three keys in it to cover all our functionality needs. **However**, I believe the distance between the SO key and other keys is too small. With regular keyboards, one needs to span a moderately wide distance to hit Ctrl and C or V. People that already have copy-pasting capability hardwired in their muscle memory will have trouble re-adjusting to The Key™.

I suggest widening the gap between SO key and other keys, preferably to match our older regular keyboards' average distance. (And perhaps adding X key as well to accommodate cut-pasting members of the community).

#### 2. THE USE OF STACK OVERFLOW KEY

What will be the default functionality of SO key? Is it customizable through a driver or interface app? Or will it be a one-time configuration at pre-order/purchase/install? This needs to be clearly stated in advance.

I hope the SO key has a freely customizable functionality by the user. One might want to use the key to mark as duplicate one day, downvote the next day, flag as VLQ the next next day, and so on. The ever changing necessity and mood of the community members in terms of interacting with the site and performing their community services should be accommodated in form of customizable key function.

#### 3. UPDATES

This is tightly connected to complaint/feedback no 2. Will The Key™ have updates over time? When the site is updated (perhaps new flag or close reason, new upvote/downvote, "thank you" buttons, etc. etc. etc.) can The Key™ keep up with it? I'm worried The Key™ will be quickly outdated and the community will be forced to purchase again next year (April 1, 2022) to cope with the quickly growing site.

If there's updates to The Key™'s software, in what form? Rolling updates? Update streams? Manual installs?

### Conclusion

I am very excited to have The Key™. I hope my complaints/feedback will be heard, as I'm one of the community members who will be seriously invested in using it. I have very high hopes on this.

I am waiting for your response. Pre-ordered 2 already so far for my personal and office use.

Comment: it would slide all over the desk and then flip over and be really annoying! And one has to consider ergonomics. Would they make a tiny little gel-wrist pad to go with it?

Comment: Wait... how did you pre-order this?

Answer (score 10):

I got seriously mad when I thought for a moment that SO was going to start profiting off other people's code my making users pay *them* to copy/paste code! How dare they! Would I also have to pay to copy/paste code from solutions or questions I had submitted?

Then I saw the picture of **The Key** and I fell in love with it. However I would seriously consider minimizing further by making it just two keys!

Comment: I say minimize it even further. Make it one key - but pressure sensitive. (Configurable of course.)

Comment: It would have to be interval-sensitive where pressing the one button multiple times sends it into multiple modes. It's like morse code!

Answer (score 9):

The [Missionary Church of Kopimism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missionary_Church_of_Kopimism) has upvoted this post.

[image: Missionary Church of Kopimism]

Answer (score 7):

For those looking for actual functionality like this, you can get a gaming mouse and macro your Mouse 3, 4, and 5 buttons to do the same thing. I currently copy/paste code with my thumb, and I suppose you could macro the middle finger button to mark as duplicate.

Comment: What do you mean by *"...macro your Mouse..."* (it seems incomprehensible)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen "macro your Mouse 3, 4, and 5 buttons". u cut it off

Comment: @PeterMortensen *macro* is a non-existent verb shorthand to say that you can create and apply a macro. Some mice like Razer and Logitech come with quick macro functionality. It takes a few seconds to do copy/paste, and a few minutes to try to do something like downvote question.

Comment: But how do you move a page/folder back and forth in a browser/explorer? My (11) mousebuttons are way to preciouse...

Comment: Only 11? 18 on my mouse, not including non-configurable scroll up, scroll down, and setting switch. It makes me very good at accidentally pressing buttons when I just want to pick it up.

Comment: Middle finger button will be the right-click. Do you mean clicking the mouse wheel? Not every mouse has that functionality. Downvoted. (+1)

Comment: @Nuclear03020704 You downvoted (+1)?

Answer (score 6):

I'm disappointed by the design. Anno 2021 I think we deserve better than bare metal parts showing from underneath the keys.

Can I suggest you re-engineer the design and make the keys 'sink' partway into the housing, so that we have a smooth design to look at?

Answer (score 6):

My heart just fell to my toes. Here we go again. **Another** paid QA forum, just like Stack Overflow was designed to replace.

And, then, Behold and Wonder, I laughed out loud.

Comment: It was an April Fool's Joke. No one would actually charge you to copy and paste.

Comment: pinterest would if they could

Comment: @nettie That's coming in the next update.

Answer (score 6):

3 keys are too many, you just need 2:

[image]

Stackoverflow key is the Stackoverflow key, copy key is the copy key. Pressing the Stackoverflow and copy keys together gives you the function of a paste key.

If you can reach the goal with 2 points of effort, never do 3!

Comment: Pushing binary combinations to infinity and beyond.

Comment: Nah, Stack + C + V = Close Vote

Comment: If you press **V** by itself, it downvotes. You can turn The Key™ upside down for an upvote.

Comment: @VLAZ It would be even nicer with an orange LED so when you upvote (or downvote) it could light up.

Comment: You only really need one key, you just might have to start using morse code commands. See also: [Unary number system](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system)

Comment: One of the points of macro keys is to avoid having to press more than one key (dedicated keys).

Answer (score 5):

I believe as the [answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406407/5049813) [show](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406400/5049813), Stack Overflow could have actually made a little bit of money by making these into a real limited item.

I certainly would have considered it!

Maybe next year they'll release digital versions with NFTs attached!

Answer (score 4):

One thing strikes me as odd though... "*may* glow in the dark"... Does that mean there's radioactive Radium inside of the keys, and that its radioactive decay may have progressed far enough to stop glowing if you're out of luck?

Comment: I hope not. I've already ordered mine...

Comment: I've looked into this question and for legal reasons I can neither confirm or deny radoactive material was employed to make The Key glow.

Comment: @CesarM By the lawyers' request?

Comment: @Anonymous yes. Every word of that comment was vetted, looked over and approved. Every. Word.

Comment: @CesarM I will neither confirm or deny that I just discussed with the legal department and they confirmed it.

Answer (score 4):

A piercing edition of “The Key™” to upvote/downvote **depending on how we shake our heads when looking at a post** would be nice.

| upvote | downvote |
| --- | --- |
| [image: image upvote] | [image: image downvote] |

Comment: Say you're in an audit and notice a dark spot on the ceiling so you look up... and down again... and back at your computer screen and you're banned for 1 year.

Answer (score 4):

What an excellent April Fool's I knew this was one the minute that I saw it...but this is definitely one of the gimmick products that I would like to see not just die after April 1st
To be able to program macros with it would be awesome.

Answer (score 4):

With only 3 buttons, you can do a multitude of combinations:

- Pressing <kbd>[image: Stack Overflow]</kbd> (that actually looks pretty good with key formatting) will type "https://stackoverflow.com/" and press enter
- Pressing <kbd>C</kbd> will copy (surprise, surprise)
- Pressing <kbd>V</kbd> will paste (I'm a genius, aren't I?)
- Pressing <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>V</kbd> together will cut
- Pressing <kbd>[image: Stack Overflow]</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd> will press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Pressing <kbd>[image: Stack Overflow]</kbd> and <kbd>V</kbd> will press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Pressing <kbd>[image: Stack Overflow]</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>V</kbd> together will press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>

Some of us might have a use for this and maybe even completely ditch the real (sorry, *large*) keyboard.  They actually do have a good idea here.  Just can you make the price a *little* lower, please?

If I get around to it, I might make some Python code that does this.

Comment: This isn't reddit to do something like _"if this gets enough upvotes, I'll...."_. Just pointing it out.

Comment: @10Rep I'm not using this as a tactic to get upvotes, I'm saying that if enough people like my idea (which would probably mean they would upvote), I'll put the effort into it.  I think there's a difference.

Comment: I understand that.... I'm just saying that reddit culture may or may not appeal to some users.

Answer (score 3):

Nah, I'll just stick to X's "**highlight to copy, middle-click to paste**" system, thanks (which also seems to happily evade this particular usage restriction ;-P). It's the **essential** feature that I miss most when using other OSes; well, that and the (sloppy-)focus-follows-mouse option…

Answer (score 3):

LOL. 'It "may" glow at night', "the latest in copy/pasting technology"

HAHA, great work guys

First I wasn't understand what is going on, I tried to copy one more time, and it did copied, so I thought it's a bug and I have unlimited copy/pasting without the key :D, I reloaded the page, and I still can copy!, I looked at the date, it's 2 April , oooooh, not again.

I remember the mic duck from the last year, was funny too "analyzing your question ..."

Answer (score 2):

We are programmers, aren't we?

Just open up development console (it's `CTRL+Shift+J` on Chrome) then enter:

```javascript
localStorage.copyBudget = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.toString();
```

Then enjoy the infinite copy paste

Comment: I'm a simpleton. Hitting dismiss in the UI works fine.

Comment: [There's an entire post I made about this "bug".](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406465/8384089)

Comment: More like vulnerability rather than ordinary bug. Because it isn't glitching (or any accidental error) but can be broken intentionally.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to rig the keys to flag an question as duplicate for the C key, and low quality for the V key (because, like... that's what everyone does these days).

Funny enough, this actually *does* seem like something that *would* be worthwhile.

Maybe not, $40 (my gaming keyboard was only ~$10 more), but like... seriously.

Sometimes I feel like copy/pasting is the only thing that I do on Stack Overflow.

This would be a nice little trinket that you could buy from Stack Overflow - kind of like a marketplace, but it's this in place of the shirts and mugs.

I definitely *would* want to go around bragging to my friends that I have the exclusive Stack Overflow copy-paste keyboard, they would be *so* jealous!

Seriously though, please *do* make this available to buy, I would *definitely* buy it (**if** you lowered the price)!

Answer (score -3):

I was GENUINELY scared until I realised it was April Fools. Not because of how expensive y'all are complaining it was, but because of the massive popup that told me I only had 3 copy and pastes for free. At first glance, I thought a paywall/subscription was being added to get unlimited pastes (like LastPass with devices). Then I read the box and quickly calmed down as I realised it was April 1st, and how ridiculous the key idea was.

Comment: In a more serious note: this post taught me that LastPass has paste limit.

Answer (score -3):

I actually thought this was real until I saw the April 1 tag on the blog post.  It was very convincing.

Answer (score -5):

There's no warning or disclaimer **not** to use it **incorrectly** for Q&As on our sites:

> "Answers that merely parrot information that someone has already provided earlier (for some significant amount of time earlier) in lesser detail don't add any value. ..." - answered May 20 '14 at 17:20 [Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255572/3648282)

> "Downvote if the question:
>
> - **Doesn't show research effort**
>
>   - Asking us to do ... anything, with no attempt to do so oneself.
>   - The question can be answered with a copy-paste from the manual.
>   - The question can be answered by copying directly from one of the results in the first page of a Google search of the title (or similar). ..." - answered Apr 29 '14 at 15:06
>     [Bernhard Barker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252747/3648282)

> "**Original is Best**
>
> I am sure many tag wikis are written in good faith, but there needs to be some guidance on how to do so.
>
> In an ideal world, if you are not writing an original tag wiki, then do not suggest the edit. Within the pool of talent on SO there would be many capable people who can author original tag wiki content, it is a matter of encouraging people to do so and discouraging people to copy and paste content. Any original work on the site, as with posts, then falls under the licencing conditions of the site.
>
> Whilst the preference is to have tag wikis to be original content, there are still many tag wikis being suggested that contain copied content. Frequently this content is copied and pasted with a link to the original site, but not formatted correctly. .." -
> community wiki 10 revs, 3 users 56% - [user3956566](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318338/3648282)

It needs a Smart Paste™ feature, where when pasting to one's own code a comment is included attributing the source, and when pasting here from elsewhere a [enter image description here] styled boilerplate is inserted to encourage proper attribution.

Comment: There used to be a service called Tynt that, when installed onto a site, would automatically append text you copied from the site with "Read more:" and the source URL. [Except said link contained tracking code so it was tracking and possibly monetizing your clipboard actions.](https://daringfireball.net/2010/05/tynt_copy_paste_jerks)

Comment: @BoltClock, some websites have some JavaScript where when you copy it adds that site's URL or other info. --- Apparently needs to add SOH too.

Answer (score -7):

I hate to be "that guy", but I really, *really* don’t like April Fools.

It would’ve been fine if it was just this post, but now I am getting annoying
popups when trying to help people. Not cool. Here is a [uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin) filter to kill it, for any other Oscar the Grouch like me:

```
stackoverflow.com##.ps-fixed
```

> [image: oscar]

Comment: Hey Steven! Sorry to hear that you're frustrated with the popups. There is a "Don't show again" button on the maximized popup if you want to disable the popups for good, but uBlock also works. Happy copying!

Comment: @StevenPenny - agreed.

Comment: **Not cool**, indeed cc @KylePollard

Comment: @Steven Penny I'd recommend _against_ blocking `.ps-fixed` with your adblocker - that's a class from our design system and would be used by other features on the site. You might have better luck targeting elements that contain `unlimited` somewhere in their IDs or classes.

Comment: @KylePollard better luck? How about stop making it hard for users to modify their own style, and give it a proper ID or unique Class so that it can be removed?

Comment: @StevenPenny there's four elements and they do have unique classes: `.js-unlimited-notice-open`, `.js-unlimited-notice-closed`, `.js-modal-unlimited` and `.js-popover-unlimited-toast`. I was recommending against blocking all `.ps-fixed` elements because that will hide anything on the site that is in a fixed position, as opposed to just this prank.

Comment: @KylePollard Or as you said, you could click "Do not show again", a button designed exactly for this purpose.

Comment: @KylePollard Sadly, after pressing "Do not show again", it popped up again in the same browser session... on April 2nd (well at least that bit was amusing).

Answer (score -7):

This is an April Fools joke? Phew!

I wouldn't put it past the current management to actually introduce something like this...

Comment: @Anonymous because it's insulting the current management, I contributed a downvote towards this. Not only does it insult _actual human beings_, but it also demeans all the work the devs and management are doing behind the scenes. Aditionally, it's counterproductive to throw blame around in answers when something is clearly a joke/prank.

Answer (score -8):

The Opening Post is very unclear, if you ask me. What is it about? As far as I understood it, it is about some new form of keyboard, but it is hard to understand anything more. What are the "three keys" there?

Comment: [Maybe this will clarify.](https://www.calendardate.com/todays.htm)

Answer (score -18):

The problems here are:

a) The world has multiple time zones, and (depending on Daylight Savings, etc) it may only "April 1st" everywhere in world at the same time for 1 hour. To fix that the "joke" would need to be enabled/disabled based on the user's time zone. It appears that this is not happening properly (e.g. I didn't see this "April fool's day" joke until the 2nd of April). This is made worse by the tradition (in some countries) that April fool's day jokes are made on the morning of April 1st, and are considered "backfired" ("You're too late, you're the fool!") if they occur on the afternoon of April 1st.

b) Stackoverflow is primarily targeted towards professionals, not children, and not "adolescent adults". Even if they can get the timing correct it would still be inappropriate.

c) A significant number of people don't observe April fool's day at all (e.g. simply not part of the culture in their region).

d) The combination of these facts are likely to cause people to assume that Stackoverflow is infected with malware (which, while "unlikely", is more plausible than childish nonsense; even if the victim is lucky enough to see it on the 1st of April).

*Notes: Socially biased voting (e.g. that don't count the number of people that temporarily left this site in disgust) is skewed towards those that liked the joke and should not be considered an accurate indicator of appropriateness. Moderators trying to distort feedback by deleting detractor's comments make this worse.*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joke

Comment: Your obsessive exaggerated disgust at this was an April fools day joke too, right?

Comment: @DavyM: I'm serious. Due to the "question and answer" format (and target audience), Stackoverflow barely tolerates opinions. Jokes have no place here.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of "April fool's day" but if other people like it I play along. Folks at SE put some effort into this and I thought the result was humorous and entertaining. +1 for the  dissenting critique.

Comment: Legit criticism that is not malicious.