# Using the new Stackexchange keyboard, I have trouble coding

Tags: discussion, april-fools

I was lucky enough to get a prerelease version of the new [Stackexchange keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?thekey), but it makes it very hard to code. For example, it has taken me half an hour to type this question. Is there a better way than copy-pasting curly braces and other special characters?

Comment: It only has three keys.

Comment: I was really quite upset with SO for this new money-making formula and wanted to see other's reactions, so I googled it and then literally laughed at my foolishness :).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Announcing "The Key™" - copy paste like you've never done before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406398/announcing-the-key-copy-paste-like-youve-never-done-before)

Comment: @JeanneDark Not really, and my unused fingers start having adverse symptoms as well. I think I might buy seven additional keys to get them occupied.

Comment: I think you should be copying the entire code, not individual characters.

Comment: @user13145713 I have to admit it, it took me a moment to connect this new product to today's date. But the internet has become so crazy that there is little that surprises me anymore. Every day 4/1.

Comment: @VLAZ I think Stackexchange will soon nudge us towards the private conversation service, but thanks for the suggestion. My main problem is that the code exists only in my head. Perhaps there will be a solution for that next year. I may have to delay release until then. For now, over and out.

Comment: I love how everyone posting questions about The Key is posting them on the main site instead of Meta. This is about the third or fourth one I've seen. It's like an April Fools' joke inside an April Fools' joke.

Comment: @F1Krazy eh, in fairness, that's where the advert shows up.

Comment: that is one of most useless things in this world. for 40 ah it is the first of april

Comment: How could you actually get a prerelease version?

Comment: It was available for a limited time and limited number of users.