# How to copy code from StackOverflow without paying the subscription?

Tags: discussion, april-fools

It seems that StackOverflow wants to put a lock on the copy of the code from the platform.
Is it possible to copy it from the source code?

Thanks

Comment: Happy April fools

Comment: I lost the cognition of time (programming)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Announcing "The Key™" - copy paste like you've never done before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406398/announcing-the-key-copy-paste-like-youve-never-done-before)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions:

1. Take a picture of the code then copy it to your codebase. I suggest a Polaroid camera, so you don't have to wait for long for the picture to develop.
2. Use a voice recorder and read out the code. Then you can play back and re-type it.
3. Use a CRT monitor and leave it turned on to where the code is. Wait until the burn-in sets in. You can then move the monitor to any other machine and see the code.
4. If you don't have a CRT monitor or you're in a hurry, you can just use a permanent marker on your monitor and trace over the code.
5. This is a bit hacky, but for code on Stack Overflow (or other websites), you can get the HTML and try to parse it with regex in order to extract the code. You just need to make a regex that matches the code you want to extract.
6. Hire infinite monkeys and give them infinite type writers. Alongside all the works of Shakespeare, they'll also produce all possible code. Simply get the one that you need.

Comment: Very good solutions! The first is often used by my clients to send me material.

Comment: It's an industry standard, yes. You can of course scan the picture and place it in an Excel file, if you want to send it to anybody.

Comment: First two didn't work, but the solution 3 worked perfectly for me.

Comment: lol! Nr. 5.. Tony the Pony is going to get you for that :)

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is the best option by far! Even reminds us of the best answer in Stackoverflow EVER: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags :D

Comment: +1 This is the hardest I've laughed all day. Even more than the original April Fool's joke itself. :D

Comment: Wait, I thought parsing regex with html is cursed....or sorry, hegex with rtml. I hope noone tries it, else they suffer the wrath of pony the tony.

Comment: I would add "memorize the source code completely" to the list.

Comment: Method 7: ignore it breeze it's an April fool's joke.

Comment: In #1, I think that "copy it by hand" was intended to say "retype it by hand", since the number of copies you may make is limited.

Comment: @BenVoigt The "copy" part is implementation detail left for free implementation. You're also allowed to train a parrot to speak out the code it sees in a picture and run that through a text-to-speech program.

Comment: @VLAZ: I am quite certain that text-to-speech-assisted-parroting does not meet the "by hand" restriction, which is your own verbiage.  (Verb everything, but conveniently *parrot* already is a verb)

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks, I've amended #1.

Comment: Train the parrot to syntax check too. *"dummy forgot a dot.... forgot a dot...forgot a dot"*

Comment: @charlietfl This violates the Single Responsibility Principle. You need one parrot for the dictation, then one parrot to check for dots, one parrot for semicolons, etc.

Comment: I think that *transcribe* might be the correct verb to use, as it includes typing by hand, text-to-speech-assisted-parrot operation, etc, while avoiding running afoul (a fowl?) of the restriction levied on *copy* and *paste*.

Comment: Unable to reproduce bypassing this by parsing regex, I ran into some [u̸n̷e̵x̷p̷e̷c̷t̷e̶d̶ c̵͇̚o̵̹͗n̶̼̈s̸̯̍e̷̡͛q̶͎̀ṳ̸̏ë̷̟́n̸̝͊ĉ̴̢e̴͍͛s̴̪̋](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3023052)

Answer (score 9):

To use the flow, you must pay the toll!

Happy April 1st