# How often do people actually copy and paste from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, statistics, april-fools

My name is David, I am the Senior Data Analyst on the Marketing team. I am new to the team but am not new to copying from Stack Overflow. I am very excited to share my first community-facing analysis. Expect more to come!

As I am sure many of you saw, this year’s April Fools joke was to limit the number of copies someone could make from Stack Overflow. Although it started as a joke, we finally had the opportunity to answer many longstanding questions about user behavior. Take a look at our new blog post [How often do people actually copy and paste from Stack Overflow? Now we know.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/19/how-often-do-people-actually-copy-and-paste-from-stack-overflow-now-we-know/) to see what we found out.

Running this year’s joke was a team effort, and my responsibility was to analyze the millions of copy events we captured. Feel free to ask me anything or add your opinion on how you interpret the results.

Comment: Interesting analysis. Is there a correlation with reputation and copying code of questions instead of answers? I've seen some questions by low-rep users where they copied the code of a question, instead of the corrected code in the answer below, and it contained the same error the question was about.

Comment: That post only discusses copying, but what about *pasting*? I frequently copy from questions but only to post in my comments or answers. It would be interesting to see how many copies were made with a direct paste into the thread (as a comment or answer). Perhaps a "quote from question" alternative should be added to answers?

Comment: Given that such an overwhelming majority of the copies are from 0 rep users, i'd hazard a guess that the number of users doing it to paste into an answer or comment are... well, substantially smaller

Comment: @KevinB True, but as the data shows the copying seem to decreases as reputation increase, but how about pasting? Does it increase as the reputation increase? Still interesting to know. :)

Comment: Does it include copying the link provided by the `share` button?

Comment: @Yatin I'm 100% sure it is relevant. In 6 to 8 years you want to find this. I'm sure with this tag that will help narrow down the results enough.

Comment: Thanks for posting this here, instead of relying on the blog comments section for feedback.  The blog comments section is pointless.

Comment: While the analysis is interesting bigger size when more users with same rep copy on the Copy Per User Per Reputation plot would help. Similarly the plot of Copy Events by Post Score does not reflect how many questions are in each dot, or the Total Copies by Grouped  Post Score and Post Type doesn't take into account the frequency of each group of score. Hope this data helps provide more useful content and value to users, the community and the company. Last a technical question. If cookies were involved in obtaining the data, how do you take into account blockers or non-consent users?

Comment: Is there some data missing in [that empty space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba8Y1.png)? I'm not sure why "We can plainly see.."

Comment: @Scratte Something isn't loading for you properly, I see [this image](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/hkdnDDP4Vx0XOMt_VWX09qKURy2k6Mr6EK2eL1JIZm0HCCe0GDPJocagTcAK5jtl7AtQbIlf_f4wE_A2-JC73X6b1s1ULifQ-9GL2JpiL1k67W3VAjKhwqcDFtHqGkVLQk-L-Tpf) in that space.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Thank you. I think.. this was perhaps timing or something. They're loading for me now. 30 minutes ago they weren't in any browser I tried.

Comment: On my main site (TeX.SE, >20K rep) I copy a lot from questions, to try out the code on my own machine and provide a solution, similar to @Someprogrammerdude. Is there a correlation between copying from questions and reputation (on SO)?

Comment: @ErikA, Thank you! There is a correlation between Reputation and Count of Copies Per User when segmenting Questions and Answers but in both cases, it was very week and not conclusive. Answers had a negative correlation and Questions had a positive correlation. Intuitively this makes sense; lower rep users copy more answers and higher rep users copy more questions (likely to then answer them). But since these trends were not significant and question copies make up less than 10% of all copies I grouped everything to show the overall trend that lower rep users are copying.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, we did not create a paste event. But if we did we still would not capture what the actual text was. So they could copy/paste from SO or copy/paste from their own code. We could create some loose logic where if there was a copy and paste within n seconds then we can assume it was a paste from the question. But that's a big assumption.

Comment: @Tomerikoo, no we did not capture if they copied the share button.

Comment: @llrs, By looking at Count of Copies we are able to normalize data. If we include total users and posts the data would be massively skewed towards lower rep/score as the majority of questions and users have a low score/rep. Doing this we were able to conclude; most copies come from lower anonymous or 0 rep users, lower score questions get more gross copies but higher score questions get more copies per power (aka are being reused more).

Comment: "When looking at this visualization, it appears that as Reputation increases, the Count of Copies Per User decreases." "This relationship is present but is not very strong" Is it not clear that the 2 columns around 100 rep are high because those people belong in the 1st 2 columns but have the association bonus? Did you not normalize per the bonus?

Comment: So you cut & pasted this from your [meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363436/266284) version?

Comment: It would be interesting to see how many of the tens of millions of users who copy-pasted code properly followed the CC-BY-SA license in attributing the content.  I'm guessing fewer than 0.0001%.

Comment: @DavidGibson Not sure what your "get more copies per power" means. But what I'm understanding here is that most of the value of the site is not the most famous questions but those rare obscure answers were only 1-10 people have some interest (and who are not logged in). However, you don't show any plot confirming this (besides showing that most copies are done by not logged in users).

Comment: Copy from question related to edit and answer could be nice. Most of my copy past should be on editing/formating a question. or when crafting an answer for the question.

Comment: It may also be interesting to compare the number of copies to the number of visits that happened during the test time. Something like a copy probability. On the other hand it's not a surprise that the top most copied tag combinations do not have many items. The smaller the size, the higher the fluctuations, the higher the chance to be at the top or bottom of any ranking.

Comment: I can see the blog post in the side bar, I regularly avoid it... I've got to ask what is the point in this meta post at all?

Comment: @Sayse Better format for giving feedback (see Robert Harvey's comment above).

Comment: @Trilarion - Thanks, I still dont see how the fact that the blog is underdeveloped is a reason to post what is effectively spam on here

Comment: @llrs in regards to the cookie usage - we didn't use cookies directly in our implementation of copy analytics. However, our analytics collection depends on having the "Performance Cookies" cookie setting turned on. If you had this setting disabled, you have opted out of analytics and would not have been part of this data.

Comment: Many thanks @KylePollard for the clarification.

Comment: Tagging this post [april-fools] is a very bad idea. I know, I know, it was probably tagged [the-key], not [april-fools] but the end result is the same. [Please desynonymize those two tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363069/348196).

Comment: Does the stat *"52.4% of copies come from answers that are not accepted"* hide the fact that many questions have multiple answers? So the accepted answer might have been copypasted more often, but the total of the non-accepted might be higher overall?

Comment: @DavidG "Does the stat "52.4% of copies come from answers that are not accepted" hide the fact that many questions have multiple answers?" Not in the sense that the statement does claim something that is wrong, but more in the sense that it should not be very surprising that there is a considerable amount of copies from unaccepted answers. There are just so many of them and often enough they even have higher scores than the accepted answers.

Answer (score 18):

In general, I enjoyed reading this research, and it's great to know that you took the opportunity to collect some usage data. On the other hand, the section "Are accepted posts copied more?" felt a bit thin. Quoting a few parts:

> When we think of an accepted answer, we may think it is the best one, and infer it is copied much more than non-accepted answers. Looking at the data, however, we find 52.4% of copies come from answers that are not accepted. (...)
>
> It is worth noting that a question may not even have an accepted answer.

This seems to suggest that the counts were mixed together without the critical context of whether there was an accepted answer to consider. This is a common concern, which was recently [depicted in comic form](https://www.monkeyuser.com/2020/election/). The additional set of research questions that (IMO) are useful would be:

- Of all answers copied, how many of those were on questions with a "competing" accepted answer?
- In a question containing an accepted answer, how likely was it for a user to copy from non-accepted other answers instead of the accepted answer?
- When copying from a non-accepted answer, how likely was it to have a higher score than the accepted answer?
- When copying from an accepted answer, how likely was the question to have a competing answer with a higher score?

The collected data should still enable y'all to gather additional insight on this matter, and on whether users are paying substantial attention to the green tick in their copying activity.

Comment: Username checks out

Comment: You are correct! When looking at the results we did not include if there was an Accepted answer to even be copied. For this first analysis, we wanted to answer the high level questions. Luckily what you mentioned is possible to answer with additional research and aligns with the type of things we want to further dig into.

Comment: In addition to the above critique (which I agree with), there is also the simple fact that not-accepted answers **far** outnumber accepted answers. For accepted answers to have nearly 50% of the copy events in and of itself strongly suggests accepted answers are far more preferred overall. Many questions with answers have no accepted answer at all, and very few questions have exactly one answer where that answer is accepted.

Comment: @aheze E_net4's usernames are... dynamic ;)

Comment: For those 1 month later who will see a different username: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg5Jn.png. Now you can understand @aheze's joke :)

Comment: @10Rep You actually already missed it. I don't have a "proof", but at the time the comment was posted it was `E_net4 the downvoter`

Comment: that's a rather deep comic

Answer (score 13):

Can you tell whether material copied from a question was (almost immediately) pasted into an answer?

When writing an answer, I quite often need to refer to some of the material in the question, especially if there's any danger of the question becoming a chameleon question (changing a lot) and will copy and paste relevant sections of the code from the question into my answer.  Sometimes, I even copy running text into a quote block.  I also copy the code out of the question to test it on my machine and debug it before pasting the revised code back into an answer.

I expect that the answer to my headline question is "no", for a variety of reasons, but copying the material into an answer to critique it is one reason for copying from even down-voted questions.

Comment: You are correct that we cannot tell if a copied question was pasted into an answer. I saw a large amount of copied questions with a score of  **0** and **1-5** (see figure title *Total Copies by Grouped Post Score and Post Type*).  This leads me to believe exactly what you mentioned. Users are copying the lower score question either to replicate it or to reference it in their own answer. At least they are doing this more than the high score questions which likely have multiple answers already.

Comment: As I wrote at the time, my knee jerk reaction to a potential copy limit was to bail from SO and never return. If I could not copy asker code to run it through my tools or even paste into an answer, I could not effectively answer questions and the site would become useless to me almost immediately. Fortunately I realized the date and unfortunately you all have to keep on putting up with me.

Comment: I agree. "copy and paste relevant sections of the code from the question into my answer", I feel like this needs to happen to some degree for almost every answer where code is involved.

Comment: "I saw a large amount of copied questions with a score of 0 and 1-5" - I think this depends on the context. Was the presence of the number of views or overall popularity of the tag taken into account? If not, then the conclusion might not be warranted (although the my gut feeling tells me this should be the case)

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, that's what I do, copy from everywhere in the page if I need to paste when building an answer.

Answer (score 5):

How did **The Key** influence the amount of copying? And in general, how did it change over time? I'm genuinely curious but that aspect seems to have been left out of the post :/

Comment: Funny you mention that. I think I copied less during "The key" :) But I also know I'm probably an unusual copier, since I tend to copy the first sentence of where I'm at in a post every 10 minutes or so. Then I paste it in a file, so when my system (OS) dies on me, I can quickly find where I was. I also copy my own comments if I want to edit them and the grace period has ended. Perhaps there are more corner case users then just me :-)

Comment: While the joke was live we actually saw slightly more web traffic but did not see more copies. I was expecting copies to spike but that was not the case. Maybe people took the joke seriously and limited their copies to just 3...

Comment: What is The Key?

Comment: @user253751 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406398/announcing-the-key-copy-paste-like-youve-never-done-before

Answer (score 4):

The really surprising (and also a bit depressing) thing is that every day a million more copy actions take place on Stack Overflow and still after more than a decade of development there is no copy button on code snippets (at least last time I looked, I'm using a user script) that would save people from having to manually select code every time. It's also not that it hasn't been [asked often enough](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32625/shortcut-or-button-for-copying-posted-code-from-stack-overflow). There are user scripts that help out, but still, just think about all the time that has been lost, maybe even whole lifetimes if you add everything together.

And once you have all the JavaScript available to track and analyze who copies what, it might be simple to add a copy button. It cannot be that the dev team wasn't able to do it.

So, as nice as it is, instead of the April joke and some data analysis I would have wished that resources were put into the implementation of feature requests instead.

Comment: I'm surprised that no one payed much attention to this.  I've lamented the same thing myself for years and years.

Answer (score 3):

*Preface: I might be missing something obvious since I missed the fun on that day (read: not having a chance to copy-paste anything on Stack Overflow), but...*

---

The blog mentioned that it tracked some attributes, including

> [...] question answer or comment, code block or plain text [...]

- While this might be trivial stats for some, did it also track copying the *title* of the question (e.g. for providing comments to link to other questions)?
- Not important, but did it also track *any* copy-paste events, even on non-Q&A part (e.g. The community bulletin, linked/related questions, or even Hot Network Questions)?

Comment: We did not directly track the title of the question but that can be derived from the `PostId`. We only tracked copies on SO but are exploring how this can be used across the network and in SO for Teams.

Comment: @DavidGibson sorry, perhaps I worded the question wrongly. What I intended to ask was: were users copying the title of the question also tracked/counted? The same for the second point, whether users copying anything else other than the Q&A (& comment) part were also tracked/counted?

Comment: Oh, I see. No, the only text that counted was Question, Answer and Comments.

Answer (score 2):

I edit a lot of posts:

1. Were copy-pastes from inside the editor counted in any way?
2. Were copy-pastes from outside the editor counted where the user went on to edit that same question?
3. Were copy-pastes counted in the scope of the review queues?

Because if they were I'd expect the most prolific copy-editors to be featured among the registered users with highest number of copy-pastes. (I didn't actually copy anything for my own use during this period).

Comment: There was no tracking of pastes. Inside the editor was not tracked. If you copied from outside the editor, if it was the body of a post or a comment, it would have been tracked. Review queues were not tracked, just the `/questions/{id}` page.

Answer (score 2):

I would love to see this in a longer setting: are there seasons? what kind of copying is seasonal? is there any sort of tendency? etc.

Also, something I didn't see: is there any spread in the post score/tags buckets?

Comment: Seasonal copying, eh? :) Something tells me there should be spikes during school/uni year/semester/whatever division there is.

Comment: It should mimic other stats that we already have

Comment: @OlegValter not necessarily. There can be for certain tags with allows us to have seasonally adjusted, see if there are spikes on specific post and address the causes of those, if our new "canonical" questions/answers are really that useful, etc. a short run doesn't allow you to get that kind of insight.

Comment: @KevinB not necessarily. See ^

Comment: @Braiam - eh, well, I was partially joking. To be more serious, I agree that it is not necessary and most likely the stats will differ depending on the knowledge region (pretty sure Java will have spikes, whereas something only relevant in the industry, won't - but who knows). Anyways, I agree that it would be at worst amusing at best useful to have this data.

Comment: @OlegValter yeah, but it's good to know that there are events that could skew the analysis. For example, the [most copied comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66082397/792066) was literally an issue that only affected a very specific version of npm packages. Also, it would help us to know how to present better the information (both comments were removed and the answers edited to include them).

Answer (score -3):

The blog post is very concerning from a licensing standpoint.

From a marketing perspective, which you appear to be coming from, 40.6 million copy-pastes in 2 weeks seems like a great thing.

From a legal perspective, it's quite the opposite.  [Everything copied from this site is licensed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) under one of the CC-BY-SA versions, which require attribution of the content:

> **You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made.**

The blog post makes a single mention of licensing:

> And of course, be aware that **some code requires a certain license to use**.

That is an absurd understatement of the *attribution* requirement of all content on this site.

Licensing is a serious issue, and the CC-BY-SA license is [repeated in the site's Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service).  The Apache Software Foundation [prohibits its projects from copying code from Stack Overflow](https://www.apache.org/legal/resolved.html#stackoverflow) for this very reason.

It does not surprise me that Stack Overflow is insensitive to the rights of its users conveyed by the license under which they post: [it was the subject of much controversy less than two years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333089/stack-exchange-and-stack-overflow-have-moved-to-cc-by-sa-4-0).   It does surprise me that no lessons were learned from that kerfuffle, and you seem to be celebrating activity that in the overwhelming majority of cases violates the license granted by users posting this content.

I hope you consider editing the blog post to make the attribution requirement more clear.

<strike>Since the blog post and related commentary indicate that Stack Overflow has the ability to monitor copy/paste activity and react differently, I *strongly* recommend you consider injecting an attribution onto the clipboard when content is copied, a common practice I've seen in many sites producing creative content.   Failure to do so, in conjunction with the obvious "marketing" slant of your celebration of millions of (probably unattributed) copy-pastes, seems to indicate a lack of respect for the license your users provide content under.</strike>

Comment: I agree that SE should do more to emphasize the license of content (I would like it if they officially embraced CC0/public domain too as an option, too). Injecting attribution on copy seems a bit heavy handed. If I copy a variable name to reference it in an answer or comment I don't want to have to edit the license text out of it (which would probably cause a syntax error). If I copy an 8 word section out of a post to quote it when responding to something, I don't want 50 words of license. There's a "fair use" / "too generic to copyright" aspect too. You can't copyright printf("hello world\n")

Comment: Now if it were something that only happened if you copied a whole *code block* or the whole post or something, I'd be more OK with that. Then the only question is how to wrap the license text (maybe it'd have to generate a comment that matches the tag or something, but not every question has a language tag attached to it.

Comment: Most of the uses of code from StackOverflow are probably fair use, i.e. the snippets are so small that anyone could have com up with it and it's practically impossible to prove that the code came from here. While I think the CC-BY-SA license is useful for whole posts, we probably want people to use the pure code without any additional hurdles. That's what makes SO so useful. And CC0/public domain should definitely be a possibility.

Comment: @Trilarion I agree, I sincerely hope nobody can claim ownership of some of the snippets I've found on here. Especially when some of them are near copy/pastes of examples from the official docs.

Comment: Licensing code is a really bad thing to do IMO. Imagine if someone licensed that one-liner which they posted as an answer. That isn't a good thing...

Comment: @10Rep by SO TOS, it's licensed when you post it unless you say otherwise.  While you and I may think that's a bad thing it doesn't change the legal requirements.

Comment: @DanielWiddis laws can be wrong and immoral. I think we should either change it to say something otherwise.

Comment: @10Rep It's not a law though in this case, just an agreement between you and this platform and all other people. You only agreed to give away your thoughts under a somewhat restrictive license. Nothing we can do about it. We have to live with it. You could have posted somewhere else where the content license is less strict. But you didn't. I don't see anything immoral happening.

Answer (score -4):

Just as a suggestion, you people of Stack Overflow could add a "number of copies" indicator aside #views. Of course, this indicator could be included to answers as well. Just a thought.

Comment: If that was on every post and not just on the Question, as the #views is, I think that would be very useful. It's hard to know if anyone finds use of one's posts at all. Most users don't have accounts and I suspect a lot of users also do not vote.

Comment: @Scratte maybe even specific parts of answers/questions could be tracked. For instance, "this code snippet has been copied X times". As noted by you, up/down votes require an proactive action to feedback the author from the viewer. Copy doesn't. And even unlogged users can be tracked but in any case some care need to be taken to avoid fraud.

Comment: Yet more meta information to clutter the Stack Overflow pages.

Comment: What's next? *"Appears in github x times"*? Might be interesting to see copy count but what value does it really add?

Comment: That's an interesting thought, but with a lot of caveats to tackle to really be of use to anyone. At least it is more helpful than the number of "claps" SE once tried to add, but very close in nature.