# Is a question asking for good ways to do something really opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, questions, opinion-based

After several questions were deservedly closed when the poster couldn't act within the normal community guidelines, I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73418506/1243641) which I thought should be better-received and which addressed what I thought of as the interesting core of those deleted questions.

I asked for "useful ways" to do something, added an answer with my own approach, and requested that others do the same.

The question was closed as "Opinion-based".  I've read the [Opinion-based description](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417487/1243641), and I feel that this question does not fit into it.  This question does not seem suited for Code Review, since I'm not asking for a critique of my particular approach.  I don't ask for the "best way" to do anything, only requesting alternatives.  I certainly am not soliciting opinions.

I could of course vote to reopen and see if it happens, but I'm curious to find out, are there some obvious edits I should make to the question to improve it?  Or is this hopelessly irredeemable?  If so, why?  I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: This is just a wording problem. "Useful ways of doing something" is just a... weird way of saying "How do i do this thing", answerers are generally expected to provide useful solutions, not useless ones.

Comment: @KevinB: Hmm, of course.  I'll drop the word.  But that doesn't seem like enough of a reason for three down-votes and a closure.  (I spend much more time answering than asking, so maybe I'm just not used to it.)

Comment: @ScottSauyet writing a self-answered question is in my opinion the hardest way to contribute to SO. I'd recommend reading https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-do-i-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting - and be less concerned about unsuccessful (from your point of view) attempt.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Thank you.  That was an interesting read.  I've never tried to do this before, and maybe I'll avoid it in the future.

Comment: It seems ironic that this question about opinion-based questions on the main site has four Close votes because it's "opinion-based".  Close-voters, care to share your rationale?

Comment: **The opinion-based close vote reason isn't applicable on meta posts tagged [tag:discussion]** - those close votes are plain wrong. Some people are being confused and should refrain from moderating on meta. Kindly read the friendly [tag:discussion] tag wiki: _"A tag for questions that may not necessarily have a clear-cut right or wrong answer and often subjective. If it is not a bug or feature-request, it is probably a discussion."_ Opinion-based as a close reason mostly exists here by accident, since meta inherited a lot of reasons from the main site.

Comment: @Lundin I would appreciate it if you chimed in on that subject [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252237). We may indeed have a problem.

Comment: @E_net4thecommentflagger The usual causes of confusion regarding meta originate from the wrong assumption that the Q&A format would somehow be suitable and sensible to use for meta as well. It isn't and never was. Obviously the very meaning and purpose of a discussion is to express different opinions, hoping to reach some manner of consensus.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Is a question asking for good ways to do something really opinion-based?

Yes.

What's "good" is subjective and unclear. Instead, ask for what you really want. What counts as "good" code for you in terms that someone else can agree with regard to whether an answer satisfies those conditions? Lines of code? Lack of certain code methods like `goto` or nested `if` statements? Using some paradigm like reflection? Whatever you are thinking in your head when you say "this is good code"... ask for that instead of asking for "good".

If you can revise your question to focus on specific, objective metrics, the question might be reopened.

As an aside, it's generally not a benefit to a question to start out by saying "someone asked this question, which got closed and deleted, and then they asked it again, and that one got closed and deleted, so I'm asking it a 3rd time!". If it was closed and deleted (especially twice), there's usually a good reason, and bringing that up can cause users to look at *your* question with a more critical eye than they otherwise might, even if you are technically asking a different question.

Also, don't equate the close votes to downvotes (not that you are explicitly doing this, but for the record I voted to close the question but didn't vote up or down on the question).

Comment: Thank you.  I got rid of the "useful" qualifier.  I was simply looking for alternative techniques.  I'll check to see if there are other similar instances to remove.  As to the closed-twice bit, I was trying to set this apart from those badly-handled questions; it sounds like I conflated them instead.  Oops!  I guess I'll try to remove that as well.  I certainly don't equate close votes with downvotes; I also use them very differently.

Comment: @ScottSauyet For what it's worth, I think the question would be best if it just focused on what you closed with, "*how to turn a collection of functions into a function that generates a collection of nodes from a selector and allows you to chain those functions as methods on this collection.*" That's a clear, specific, and objective request that anyone can answer.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and the edit you made is very helpful and  much appreciated.

Comment: @ScottSauyet note that questions that ask for lists (like ‘alternative approaches’) are deemed too broad. Stick to questions where you can expect one best answer, not several.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:. Thanks.  I don't think that's quite what I was doing.  I was hoping different answers might suggest varying techniques, but I was hoping for good answers that offered single ones.  I certainly wasn't asking posters to supply lists of options.

Comment: @ScottSauyet if you are looking for alternatives you need to explain "why". Like "why does the generic method doesn't fit my use case?" etc.

Answer (score 11):

As one of the close-voters, I shall try to explain my reason(s) for casting the close vote. But first, let me state that this was not a 'simple' decision, and I was close to skipping that review.

As presented in the review (i.e. before your recent edit), the term, "useful," certainly pushed me towards closing as opinion-based – usefulness is (or can be) a very subjective concept. *But you have edited-out that particular thorn.*

So, let's now analyse it as a "How to … ?" question: Such questions would normally be posted by those who don't know how to do the task in hand, but you quite clearly ***do*** know at least one way of implementing the task. This, to me, suggests that you are looking for others to post their methods so that a comparison can be made between the various approaches … and *that* is, I believe, quite clearly opinion-based. *Unless, of course, you can highlight a specific problem in the approach you have taken, which needs addressing.*

But is it a "self-answered" question (that *may* become a useful reference, or even a canonical Q/A)? Again, I would say, "No," here, also because of the fact that you have explicitly asked for other approaches.

So, for the time being, I'll stand by my close vote (and the specific reason). However, I'm not (and never am) beyond being persuaded to reverse my decision and cast a reopen vote. Let's see what this Meta discussion yields.

---

P.S.: I'm not one of the down-voters and I don't think the question (or your answer) deserves such. That is, no doubt, the notorious "[Meta Effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/10871073)" manifesting itself.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I vote on many questions, and don't think I would ever vote to close because a question is seeking alternative approaches, but it's good to know that others *do* see that as a problem.  (So far the Meta Effect hasn't been strong; it's gone from `+0-3` to `+1-4` so far.)

Comment: @ScottSauyet With the edits, I was considering a reopen vote ... but I was too late. :)

Comment: @ScottSauyet note that there is significant difference between "here is my approach but I'm looking for alternatives because ..." and  "let's list all approaches as answers". Lack of "correctness" criteria in the later one makes such questions too-broad/opinion-based, especially when it is clear there are plenty of possible approaches (like in your case of "implement fluent interface in XXX" question - there plenty of opinions/approaches for all sorts of languages, and scoping it down to JavaScript was not enough)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: An interesting distinction.  I was definitely most interested in seeing what variety of answers might be given these days, and didn't have any really objective criteria for judging them.  Of course the question has been closed again, this time for being a duplicate of some really old, partially-relevant, questions.  If I decide to come at this again some day, I will take this into account.

Answer (score 5):

Code can be good in several ways, including but not limited to

- Short
- Readable
- Fast
- Low memory usage
- Generic
- Failsafe

These are often hard to combine. So you better choose what way you want the code to be good. Furthermore, these can often also be divided in sub categories. Take "Fast" for example:

- Small input
- Large input
- Random input
- Response time
- Throughput

Answer (score 2):

I have 20 years of experience in some programming areas.  When I see a question that is "closed as opinion", I read it anyway.  In some cases, I have tackled their problem and arrived at a "good" solution.  I will happily provide my specific experience for their specific question, yet the best I can do is "vote to reopen" and give a brief 'answer' in a Comment.  I do sometimes suggest that they start a new Question and suggest certain rewording in hopes of avoiding a second closing.

Grrr.